# Allowing a field being parsed to remain null if no input is read in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm reading in data from a web form using text boxes and inserting it into my SQL database. I had to parse the string input for 3 different text boxes to their matching data type in the database. I allow nulls in the database but when I execute the code, if I dont have a value in one of the boxes it fails when I reach the parse statement. How would I go about running the parse only if the textbox has content? Sorry I know it's probably a very easy solution but i cant seem to write anything that will compile.

** The ISBN is a MUST as it is the PK in my database so disregard my ISBN parse line. but for example, a book may have a 13digit ISBN (PK) but not have a 10 digit ISBN number, but if it does I'm required to store that in the DB

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Convert int to long for ISBN
        long lng = long.Parse(txtISBN.Text);


        //convert string to int for 10 digit isbn
        int tenISBN = int.Parse(txtP1.Text);


        //convert string to int for Vendor ISBN
        int vendISBN;
        vendISBN = Convert.ToInt32(txtVendorISBN.Text);
        vendISBN = int.Parse(txtVendorISBN.Text);


        //Table adapter object to Insert Data
        DataSet1TableAdapters.TableBookTableAdapter bookTableAdapter;
        bookTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TableBookTableAdapter();

        DataSet1TableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter courseAdapter;
        courseAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter();
        courseAdapter.Insert(courseID: txtCourseID.Text, CourseTitle: txtCourseTitle.Text);




        //Adapter insert Statement
        bookTableAdapter.Insert(ISBN: lng, courseID: txtCourseID.Text, bookTitle: txtBookTitle.Text, Ancillary: txtAncillary.Text,
            bookActive: bookActive, ActiveDate: activeCalendar.SelectedDate, InactiveDate: inactiveCalendar.SelectedDate, Author: txtAuthor.Text, Imprint: txtImprint.Text, 
            Publisher: txtPublisher.Text, EditionDate: txtEditionDate.Text, VendorISBN: vendISBN, p1: tenISBN, eBookAvailable: eBookAvailable, eISBN: txtEISBN.Text, Notes: txtNotes.Text);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I dont have a value in one of the boxes it fails when I reach the
>   parse statement.

You need to check first if your textbox has content, and you can do it like this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtISBN.Text))
  log = long.Parse(txtISBN.Text);
```

if the textbox content is null, or empty then the parse will not be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Nullable<T>` type or simply `int?` and parse each item manually. Such as.

```
int? tenISBN = null,
    vendISBN = null;

int iParse;

long? lng = null;
long lParse;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtISBN.Text) && long.TryParse(txtISBN.Text, out lParse))
    lng = lParse;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP1.Text) && int.TryParse(txtP1.Text, out iParse))
    tenISBN = iParse;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtVendorISBN.Text) && int.TryParse(txtVendorISBN.Text, out iParse))
    vendISBN = iParse;


if (lng.HasValue) //lng has value
{
    //DO Your work
}
```